# Documentation for Game Development?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, documentation, documentation-topics

We have an interesting topic request for [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/topic-requests/4438

This could be a useful topic in [Game Development Stack Exchange Community](//gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but communities have no documentation.

I would like to ask for that feature, because we can document not only computer languages/frameworks/etc, but different things: from airplanes and computer models to soup recipes.

Comment: Let's figure out whether it's viable at all in one place first before spreading it elsewhere (hence multiplying the feature requests/complaints/things to be aware of)

Comment: Its already difficult to whip the current documentation system into shape, its a bit early to talk about broadening its horizons to this scope :)

Comment: Read this on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281689/allow-documentation-in-other-stack-exchange-communities).

Comment: @StephenLeppik you're welcome to do these edits when you see posts requiring them, but please don't flood the otherwise slow-paced Meta front page by going out of your way to search for them.

Comment: @Stijn actually, I was frequently starring questions to edit for when I hit 2K. And I hit 2K. Anyway, I'm done now :)

Comment: @StephenLeppik OK, fair enough :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually, this might happen but not for a long time.  See more details in my answer on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281690/164200).

> Once it is known to work, then we can discuss the possibility of adding it to other sites but that won't be for 6-8 weeks.